# Groovy create Map from list

Tags: arrays, dictionary, groovy, associative-array

I tried to create Map (or associative array) in Groovy from two files with list, ﻿but the result is not what I expected.

```
def componentsFile = "WORKSPACE/Components" 
def linksFile = "WORKSPACE/Links"

def components = new File(componentsFile).collect { it.trim() } 
def links = new File(linksFile).collect { it.trim() } 

def result = [components, links].transpose().collect { component, link -> 
  [name: component, link: link]
}

println result
```

What I got

```
[[name:component1, component2, component3, component4, link: link1, link2, link3, link4]]
```

And what I expected

```
[[name:component1, link:link1], [name:component2, link:link2], [name:component3, link:link3], [name:component4, link:link4]]
```

Comment: when I run you script, I get what you expect to get: `[[name:a, link:A], [name:b, link:B], [name:c, link:C], [name:d, link:D]]`. Also you are trying to create a list of maps, not the map

Comment: Do you put local Lists or get values from files? And how I can create exactly Map?

Comment: local of course! where would I get your files from? I think I know what your problem is: your strings are not split by `,` and are transposed as a whole

Comment: Honestly, idk what a problem because I have files with string like: component1, component2, component3, component4 
Without any tabs or newlines, etc.. And if I provide local Lists with the same contents it works. But it doesn't work with files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to transpose the strings which contain the comma-separated values and hence you get 2 fields in the output only.

You need to split the strings beforehand:

```
def components = 'component1, component2, component3, component4'
def links = 'link1, link2, link3, link4'

def result = [ components.split( ', ' ), links.split( ', ' ) ].transpose().collect{ component, link -> [name: component, link: link] }

assert result.toString() == '[[name:component1, link:link1], [name:component2, link:link2], [name:component3, link:link3], [name:component4, link:link4]]'
```

or in case with your files (which I can't reproduce in console), the declaration of the vars would look like so:

```
def components = new File(componentsFile).text.split( ', ' )
def links = new File(linksFile).text.split( ', ' )
```